# Obtainig values from another Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I obtained the reference value for an element by it´s last appearence in a data frame (data2017) like this:

```
 data2017 <- data.frame(Ticker = c("PETR4","PETR4","VALE5","VALE5","USIM5","USIM5"),
                        Close  = c(14, 15.59, 28.10, 29.07, 8.50, 8.47))

tail(data2017[data2017$Ticker=="PETR4","Close"],1)
```

For the row with the value "PETR4" it gave me the last price of the column Close and worked just fine.
 But when i wan´t to do it automatically, filling new rows of a new column using other tickers in a Data Frame like below:

```
Reference_Prices <- data.frame(Ticker    = c("PETR4","VALE5","USIM5"),
                               Reference = c("NA","NA","NA"))



N <- nrow(Reference_Prices)
Reference_Prices$Ref <- tail(data2017[data2017$Ticker==Reference_Prices$Ticker[1:N],"Close"],1)
```

It gave me the following error:

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're just trying to get the last value for each `Ticker`? If so, just use `tapply` or `dplyr::group_by`. If not, please clarify your expected output.

#### tapply solution

```
with(data2017, tapply(Close, Ticker, function(x) x[length(x)]))

PETR4 USIM5 VALE5 
15.59  8.47 29.07
```

#### dplyr::group_by solution

```
library(dplyr)
data2017 %>% 
  group_by(Ticker) %>% 
  summarize(last_close = Close[n()])

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Ticker last_close
  <fctr>      <dbl>
1  PETR4      15.59
2  USIM5       8.47
3  VALE5      29.07
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's the idea. In fact, I'll use these values to insert new columns on an existing  bigger Data Frame and calculate returns based on these values. I'll try Tapply

Answer (score 0):

When I type in your code I don't get an error. Have a look:

```html
> data2017 <- data.frame(Ticker=c("PETR4","PETR4","VALE5","VALE5","USIM5","USIM5"),Close=c("14","15.59","28.10","29.07","8.50","8.47"))
> data2017
  Ticker Close
1  PETR4    14
2  PETR4 15.59
3  VALE5 28.10
4  VALE5 29.07
5  USIM5  8.50
6  USIM5  8.47
> tail(data2017[data2017$Ticker=="PETR4","Close"],1)
[1] 15.59
Levels: 14 15.59 28.10 29.07 8.47 8.50
> str(data2017)
'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Ticker: Factor w/ 3 levels "PETR4","USIM5",..: 1 1 3 3 2 2
 $ Close : Factor w/ 6 levels "14","15.59","28.10",..: 1 2 3 4 6 5
> tail(data2017[data2017$Ticker=="PETR4","Close"])
[1] 14    15.59
Levels: 14 15.59 28.10 29.07 8.47 8.50
> Reference_Prices <- data.frame(Ticker=c("PETR4","VALE5","USIM5"),Reference=c("NA","NA","NA"))
> Reference_Prices
  Ticker Reference
1  PETR4        NA
2  VALE5        NA
3  USIM5        NA
> str(Reference_Prices)
'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Ticker   : Factor w/ 3 levels "PETR4","USIM5",..: 1 3 2
 $ Reference: Factor w/ 1 level "NA": 1 1 1
> N <- nrow(Reference_Prices) 
> tail(data2017[data2017$Ticker==Reference_Prices$Ticker[1:N],"Close"],1)
[1] 8.47
Levels: 14 15.59 28.10 29.07 8.47 8.50
> Reference_Prices$Ref <- tail(data2017[data2017$Ticker==Reference_Prices$Ticker[1:N],"Close"],1)
> Reference_Prices
  Ticker Reference  Ref
1  PETR4        NA 8.47
2  VALE5        NA 8.47
3  USIM5        NA 8.47
> data2017$Ticker==Reference_Prices$Ticker[1:N]
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> data2017[data2017$Ticker==Reference_Prices$Ticker[1:N],"Close"]
[1] 14   8.47
Levels: 14 15.59 28.10 29.07 8.47 8.50
```

From what I see, you are assigning to the Ref column the last ticker value from your data2017 data frame.

Try pasting a printout of your console with the error message. Also, break down your code into easier to digest snippets when debugging. See what I did below.

Comment: Kamilien, the inserted column in this case assigned the last values of USIM5 to all Tickers.

Comment: Good point. This is a separate error unrelated to the poster's question, except the overall solution would need to be modified.